# Calculate 2 different select custom data attributes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate data-price attribute rather than option value, I have created the code which works fine with value but my database has the different column which I don't want to change, the below example works fine with value but I want to know what changes should I make to get the value of data-price attribute

```js
$('#CPU').on("change",function(){
    var CPU = $("#CPU option:selected").attr('data-price');
    $("#SelectedCPUResult").html(CPU);
});

// Update Product Tenure Price on select on product.php
$('#RAM').on("change",function(){
    var RAM = $("#RAM option:selected").attr('data-price');
    $("#SelectedRAMResult").html(RAM);
});
$(function () {
    var fields = $('#form1 :input').change(calculate);

    function calculate() {
        var price = 0;
        fields.each(function () {
            price += +$(this).val();
        })
        $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="CPU">CPU</label>
    <select name="CPU" id="CPU">
      <option value="">Select CPU</option>
      <option value="9.99" data-price="9.99">1 Month</option>
      <option value="19.99" data-price="19.99">3 Months</option>
      <option value="29.99" data-price="29.99">6 Months</option>
      <option value="39.99" data-price="39.99">12 Months</option>
      <!-- Actual fields -->
      <!-- <option value="1" data-price="9.99">1 Month</option> -->
      <!-- <option value="3" data-price="9.99">3 Months</option> -->
      <!-- <option value="6" data-price="9.99">6 Months</option> -->
      <!-- <option value="12" data-price="9.99">12 MOnths</option> -->
    </select>
    <span id="SelectedCPUResult">9.99</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="RAM">RAM</label>
  <select name="RAM" id="RAM">
    <option value="">Select RAM</option>
    <option value="9.99" data-price="9.99">1 Month</option>
    <option value="19.99" data-price="19.99">3 Months</option>
    <option value="29.99" data-price="29.99">6 Months</option>
    <option value="39.99" data-price="39.99">12 Months</option>
    <!-- Actual fields -->
    <!-- <option value="monthly" data-price="9.99">1 Month</option -->
    <!-- <option value="quarterly" data-price="9.99">3 Months</option> -->
    <!-- <option value="semianuually" data-price="9.99">6 Months</option> -->
    <!-- <option value="annually" data-price="9.99">12 Months</option> -->

  </select>
    <span id="SelectedRAMResult">9.99</span>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
Price: <u id="price">19.98</u>
```

Your help in this regards would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Change `.val()` to `.data('price')`. The same for `attr('data-price')`. See the docs for more info: http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: How about replace `$("#RAM option:selected").attr('data-price');` with `$("#RAM option:selected").data('price');`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when I change .val() to .data('price') it gives NAN

Comment: @null That's not the answer I was expacting

Comment: Why the question marked negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change that:

```
function calculate() {
    var price = 0;
    fields.each(function () {
        price += parseFloat($(this).attr('data-price'));
    })
    $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
}
```

You were using ".val()" (which gets the value) and I changed it to ".attr('data-price')" (wich looks for a attribute with the "data-price" name) and convert it to a float.

```js
$('#CPU').on("change",function(){
    var CPU = $("#CPU option:selected").attr('data-price');
    $("#SelectedCPUResult").html(CPU);
});

// Update Product Tenure Price on select on product.php
$('#RAM').on("change",function(){
    var RAM = $("#RAM option:selected").attr('data-price');
    $("#SelectedRAMResult").html(RAM);
});
$(function () {
    //var fields = $('#form1 :input').change(calculate);
    $('#form1 :input').change(calculate);


    function calculate() {
        var price = 0;
        $('.partial').each(function (idx, el) {
          
            price += parseFloat($(el).html());
        })
        $('#price').html(price.toFixed(2));
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <div>
    <label for="CPU">CPU</label>
    <select name="CPU" id="CPU">
      <option value="">Select CPU</option>
      <option value="1" data-price="9.99">1 Month</option> 
      <option value="3" data-price="19.99">3 Months</option> 
      <option value="6" data-price="29.99">6 Months</option> 
      <option value="12" data-price="39.99">12 MOnths</option> 
    </select>
    <span class="partial" id="SelectedCPUResult">9.99</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label for="RAM">RAM</label>
  <select name="RAM" id="RAM">
    <option value="">Select RAM</option>
    <option value="monthly" data-price="9.99">1 Month</option>
    <option value="quarterly" data-price="19.99">3 Months</option>
    <option value="semianuually" data-price="29.99">6 Months</option>
    <option value="annually" data-price="39.99">12 Months</option>
  </select>
    <span class="partial" id="SelectedRAMResult">9.99</span>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
Price: <u id="price">19.98</u>
```

Comment: It will be even better if `.data('price')` is used.

Comment: @Marcelo Myara Can you please create the whole snippet, because the function you suggested doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sure. But let me see if I get what you need straight: Your code is considering the value present on the "value" attribute of an option - and you need to change it so it consider the value present in data-price instead. Is that right? (if so, we will have to change some values present on the value attribute to check it out cause they're all identical between "value" and "data-price")

Comment: There goes the snippet.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, Thank you for help